# Package trackchanges : option "margins" buggy?

Tags: trackchanges

According to the documentation of [trackchanges](http://trackchanges.sourceforge.net/), the option "margins" should allow to write the comments in the margins :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margins]{trackchanges}
\begin{document}
  Before-Text  \annote{text}{comment}
\end{document}
```

but it won't compile. With the option "inline" instead of "margins" it works.
Did someone else encounters the problem ?

Comment: Works fine for me: 'too localized'